# I need to convert the last string from this array to capital

Tags: string

$county="Great Britain,India, Pakistan, Australia,Canada" let this be the string. I need to conver canada to CANADA and if the string does not contain Canada it should show "String not found"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to receive a helpful answer if you describe more about your problem, what language you're using, what you tried to solve it, and where you got stuck.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.